# Share with 'Start at' tag in YouTube iOS app

Tags: ios, sharing, youtube

How can I share video with "Start at" option in YouTube iOS app?

Comment: This used to be easy in Safari (desktop and portable / iOS) but it’s not easy there anymore. Hopefully the app still provides that feature. Good question - would be nice to know if it’s possible in app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

copy the link and append ?=tXs to it, with X being the number of seconds into the video you want to share at. It's also possible to specify minutes, using ?=tXmYs, where X is minutes and Y is seconds.

I don't think there's an easy way of selecting the time, you have to work it out manually.